# define argument in command line for python os.walk script

Tags: python

I am working on a larger script that walks through a directory structure to perform an action on each file.

I am having trouble figuring out how to pass the target directory as an argument in the command line (to be the starting point of the os.walk).

Can anyone advise on what I am doing wrong?

```
import os
import sys

def main():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1])
      for item in files:
        print(items)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, your original call to main has main accepting no arguments:

```
import os
import sys

def main(): # this has 0 arguments, instead you included it inside of the func.
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
      for item in files:
        print(items)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1]) # likely the source of your error since main() has the argument inside the func.
```

If you would like main to have arguments:

```
def main(args): # any generic argument to be called
    for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(args):
        for item in files:
            print(items)
if __name__ = '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1]) # specific argument called by function
```

Comment: so in "def main(args)", we're basically assigning a variable called "args" that will be assigned whatever is in the command line?

Comment: So in the function, we are assigning a generic argument (which can be anything that fits in your function). It could be a string or int or float or whatever you need. But in this case you are calling os.walk() on the argument inside the function. So the function variable args is substituted by sys.argv[1] which means that the first thing in the command line after your python command call will be substituted into this argument “args”.

Comment: if this answers your question, could you accept it so other people looking for the same answer might see this?